# Why are css and assets directories not created by default when laravel project is created?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

I have created a project using both methods via `laravel` and via `composer`.

As all tutorials and video telling that there is `css` folder under public folder `public/css/app.css`. Also resources folder have assets folder `resources/assets`.

However in both cases my project doesn't have `public/css/app.css`  & `resources/assets` folder/files.

Via `laravel` folder structure is as **follows**:

```
-->public 
 - .htaccess
 - favicon.ico
 - index.php
 - robots.txt

-->resources
 - js
 - lang
 - sass
 - views
```

Using composer folder structure is as follows:

```
-->public
 - .htaccess
 - favicon.ico
 - index.php
 - robots.txt
 - web.confi
-->resources
 - js
 - lang
 - sass
 - views
```

I am using Laravel 6.0.3.

Why I am not getting default `css` and `assets` directories after installation?

Comment: You should also read the Fronted part from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend). There is no more an `assets` folder since Laravel 5.5 I believe or around then, you should have `resources/css` folder instead. Take a look at the documentation on how to [compile assets](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel had some directory changes at version 5.7, these changes include flattening of directories. Here's a [Laravel News](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-resources-directory-changes) article for reference. Also, please read up on the latest [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend) of JavaScript & CSS Scaffolding in Laravel 6.

Comment: Latest news shows that resources folder structure is changed in higher version of `laravel` . Then what about public folder structure? In higher version we don't have css folder. Is that the case? In higher version of `laravel` do we have to load css through npm something for every project?

Comment: @NMT they won't pre-compile assets because that's the point of a framework, you should build from it, not expect something to be built within it that you MIGHT need especially on the assets that is often modified by the developers.

Answer (score 0):

In **Laravel 6** by default the **css** file are not compiled you can compile it by using **npm** first download and install **nodejs** for **npm** after that run this command : **npm install** this will download and install **node_modules** and after that run this command to compile the **css** and **js** file to your public folder **npm run dev**.